# Slick Carousel 'slickGoTo' not working on page refresh for hidden slider items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I am using slick carousel for my page navigation links and my current active menu item has "active" styling to show what page i am on.

The problem is that if i click on a menu item that was off screen on the slick track, slick would initialise its position on page reload and you would not see the "active" menu item selected which i don't like.

My solution was to simply use 'slickGoTo' method on page load, where i would capture the 'data-slick-index' attribute value and use it with 'slickGoTo' method which should solve the problem.

However, what seems to happen is if the slick item i clicked on was visible on page then the 'slickGoTo' method works just fine. But, if the item is off page it does not work.

```
// service menu slick slider
function service_menu_slick() {
    $('#service-menu').slick({
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',
        slidesToShow: 7,
        infinite: false,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1250,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 6,
                    infinite: false
                }
            }, 
            {
                breakpoint: 1100,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 5,
                    infinite: false
                }
            }, 
            {
                breakpoint: 850,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 4,
                    infinite: false
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 700,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    infinite: false
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 550,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    infinite: false
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 450,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    infinite: false
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    $serviceSlide = $('#service-menu');

    if ($serviceSlide) {

        slideIndex = $('.current_page_item.slick-slide').attr('data-slick-index');
        console.log(slideIndex);
        $('#service-menu').slick('slickGoTo', slideIndex);

    }
}
```

Comment: can you make an jsbin with everythign?

Comment: @BalajMarius I don't think so, this issue has to deal with page refresh resetting the position for me. JsBin wont work with a page reset, i tried to set it up there unsuccessfully.